# Encrypt data in postgres with php

Tags: php, postgresql

I need to store a number encrypted in my postgres database. I wanted to use mcrypt with the 3DES function, the encrypting and decrypting is working fine, but I can't store it in the database. My database field is `char(50)`.

```
$key = "this is a secret key";
$input = "123456789";

$test = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $input, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=testdb user=haxo");
$sql = "insert into test (pin) values('".$test."')";
$result = pg_query($sql); 
if (!$result) {
    $errormessage = pg_last_error();
    echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
    exit();
} 
pg_close();
```

The error I'm getting is: `ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'Ÿlä"`

Comment: quoting php.net about "mcrypt_ecb": This function is deprecated and should not be used anymore, see mcrypt_generic() and mdecrypt_generic() for replacements.

Comment: if i try this i get: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the field type BYTEA (which is for storing binary strings), then use something like PDO prepare, bindValue, execute to insert the values.

also, do You know about [sql injection](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? The coding pattern You are using is a simple recipe for trouble.

Comment: The number isnt from the user, so no sql injection.